# How do I change the color of the highlighting in the intelliSense for vs code on line hover or focus?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having trouble differentiating between selections when IntelliSense pops up. I looked through the settings but no luck, so I'm guessing it's in a config.json. Any insights? I've also attached a screenshot for clarity.

**TL;DR:** How do I change the color of the highlighting of what I have circled in the screenshot below?

[image: IntelliSense]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly isn't obvious but try:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "list.highlightForeground": "#0ee065",  // suggestions letter highlight

   // background color of the entire focused line in the suggestion box, thanks to Raphael
  "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#505200"
}
```

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because it got me on the right track. If anyone else is curious the answer is:     "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#505200"
    }

Comment: Ah, thanks I misunderstood - I thought it was the color of the letters, like `s` and `j`, that you typed to trigger the intellisense that you wanted to change.  I'll edit to include your info.

Comment: Thank you Mark, it helped me to solve my problem :)